# Regex for matching a comma, but only if preceded by N chars (including spaces)

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches a comma, but *only* if it's preceded by N chars (including spaces or other commas).  The N chars should not be included in the result, only the comma.   What regex will do this?

Comment: No ideas until we know at least what the programming language is.

Comment: Have you tried by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as a template:

```
/(?<=.{N}),/
```

where you replace N with the number of chars to precede the comma.

For example, to precede ',' by 7 chars, use this:

```
/(?<=.{7}),/
```

and it will match any 7 characters preceding the comma.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's exactly what I tried before posting this question, but unfortunately it matches the 10 chars preceding the comma. I need to match the comma itself :-(

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks, your help is really appreciated!